# rake db:migrate updates create_table block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I am resolving a conflict on schema.rb by running `rake db:migrate`

The migration changing the definition

```
create_table "data_migrations", primary_key: "version", id: :string, force: :cascade do |t| end
```

To

```
create_table "data_migrations", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "version", null: false
end
```

Are those 2 equivalent? Where does this change comes from?

Comment: They are not equivalent, the second one doesn't declare 'version' as primary key

Comment: If you have a conflict in `schema.rb` (or `structure.sql`) you're better off fixing the migrations and database then just dump a new `schema.rb`. If you're editing `schema.rb` you're almost always going down the wrong path.

Answer (score -1):

<s>Yes the above two definitions are same</s> and they pertain to "schema_migrations" which version control and store the migration version history. They only have **one column "version" which is string type and primary key for the table**. They might have been modified when rake tasks related to schema load are run.

Comment: Yes i agree that the second migration does not specify primary key but i assumed that the person asking the question has not manually modified the schema.rb and i tried explaining that how and when schema file updates. Anyways i should have clarified it in a better way.